# Question about X-rays hitting a gold leaf electroscope

Tags: electrostatics

If X-rays are incident on gold leaf electroscope , leaves always collapse whatever be the charge on leaves. Why?

Comment: I think it depends on the direction of the X-rays. If the X-rays hit one of the leafs, it would knock out some electrons of that leaf which would leave this leaf with positive charge whereas other leaf would stay almost neutral (some of the ejected electrons could end on the other leaf). This would make the two leafs attract each other.

Answer (score 1):

The X-rays ionise the air around the gold leaf electroscope.
Charges in the air of the opposite sign to that on the electroscope are attracted to the electroscope and discharge it.